# Undefined method `<=' for [["a", 1]]:Array (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

My program intends to check if a string has two charcters of interest that are within proximity to one another, as shown below:

```
def near_ab(string)
   arr = string.split("")

   a_position = arr.each_with_index.select {|element, i| arr[i] == "a"}
   b_position = arr.each_with_index.select {|element, i| arr[i] == "b"}

   if a_position - b_position <= 3
      return true
   else 
      return false
   end

end
```

Everything looks fine to me, except I get the following error:

```
`near_ab': undefined method `<=' for [["a", 1]]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Why is it saying that the <= operator is undefined?  The result of the funciton I'm calling should yield and integer on the left and compare it to another integer on the right, right?

I know there are different ways to solve this problem but I just want to know what's going on with my code above.

Any insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_with_index` will generate pairs of `[value, index]`. `select` will return some of those pairs; so `a_position` and `b_position` are both arrays of pairs. Between arrays, `-` will return elements of `a_position` that are not in `b_position`; so you don't have an integer, you have an array (more specifically, `[["a", 1]]` as your error tells you). And `[["a", 1]] <= 3` is clearly nonsense.

I suppose you wanted this:

```
a_position = arr.index("a")
b_position = arr.index("b")
```

Comment: TIL that `Array` does not `include Comparable`: `Array.included_modules #=>  [JRuby::Generators::Iterators, Enumerable, Kernel]` (with Roboto IRB), so `<=` will always raise that exception when the receiver is an array.